# Python 3.6 TYPE ERROR: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a class BankAccount to amend a text file with final balance with each transaction. My init is working fine, but deposit is not. As a new programmer, I'm assuming I'm missing something to do with the fundamentals of object-orientating.
`class BankAccount:`

```
def __init__(self, bal, file):
    self.__balance = bal
    self.__file = file
    self.__infile = open(file, 'a')
    self.__infile.write(datetime.now().strftime('Date of Account Origin: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+'\n'))
    self.__infile.write('Balance:\n')
    self.__infile.write(format(float(self.__balance), '.2f')+'\n')
    self.__infile.close()

def deposit(self, amount, file):
    self.__balance += amount
    self.__file = file
    self.__infile = open(file, 'a')
    self.__infile.write(('Date of Deposit: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+'\n')
    self.__infile.write('Balance:\n')
    self.__infile.write(format(float(self.__balance), '.2f')+'\n')
    self.__infile.close()
```

This is part of my driver file.

`def deposit(account):`
      `money = float(input('Enter amount you would like to deposit.  '))`

`account.deposit(money)`

Currently, I am getting the error:

> File "C:\Users\gonzo\Downloads\Driver.py", line 29, in deposit
>   account.deposit(money) TypeError: deposit() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'file

'

How can I fix this error, in order to record balance to the text file? I have tried but do not understand the issue and therefore how to solve it.

Comment: `def deposit(self, amount, file):` Your function needs two arguments.

Comment: Pass in a `file` description.

Comment: The correct fix is to remove the file parameter as it's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file argument from the definition of `deposit()`.  Unless you're going to change files for some reason, the `self.__file` field has the file name already stored by the `__init__()` function, so you don't need to supply it on every call.

Also, "__infile" doesn't need to be a field in the object.  It's opened, used and closed in both methods.  There's no reason to keep it around.

Here's what a pared-down deposit() function might look like:

```
def deposit(self, amount, file):
    self.__balance += amount
    __infile = open(file, 'a')
    __infile.write(('Date of Deposit: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+'\n')
    __infile.write('Balance:\n')
    __infile.write(format(float(self.__balance), '.2f')+'\n')
    __infile.close()
```

Comment: Your advice helped me solve my entire issue. My program works how expected now. Thank you very much

Comment: @kkw You're welcome.  Read the new comments, added on edit.  Pretty soon you should be learning how to use the `with` statement to make sure that files (particularly output files) get closed no matter what.